# Breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools can't be hit while the url has a hash

Tags: hash, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dZBY2/1/show/light/#1

As I did a demo page above, after marking a breakpoint,I fresh the page ,the breakpoint can't be hit.

Am I did something wrong ? It was amazing.

My Chrome version :31.0.1650.63 m.

My OS: Windows7 64bit

Comment: I can reproduce your problem using Opera 18.0.1284.68 and I also think this is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem using Chromium 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306239 was fixed recently. The fix is available in Chrome Canary or Beta and will reach stable channel in a few weeks.

Comment: My Chrome version :31.0.1650.63 m.  Thx!